# How to print double quotes inside ""?

Tags: swift, string, escaping

Can someone please tell me how can I print something in following way "with" double quotes.

"Double Quotes"

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Answer (score 307, accepted):

With a backslash before the double quote you want to insert in the String:

```
let sentence = "They said \"It's okay\", didn't they?"
```

Now `sentence` is:

> They said "It's okay", didn't they?

It's called "escaping" a character: you're using its literal value, it will not be interpreted.

---

With Swift 4 you can alternatively choose to use the `"""` delimiter for literal text where there's no need to escape:

```
let sentence = """
They said "It's okay", didn't they?
Yes, "okay" is what they said.
"""
```

This gives:

> They said "It's okay", didn't they?
>   Yes, "okay" is what they said.

---

With Swift 5 you can use enhanced delimiters:

> String literals can now be expressed using [enhanced delimiters](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0200-raw-string-escaping.md). A string literal with one or more number signs (#) before the opening quote treats backslashes and double-quote characters as literal unless they’re followed by the same number of number signs. Use enhanced delimiters to avoid cluttering string literals that contain many double-quote or backslash characters with extra escapes.

Your string now can be represented as:

```
let sentence = #"They said "It's okay", didn't they?"#
```

And if you want add variable to your string you should also add `#` after backslash:

```
let sentence = #"My "homepage" is \#(url)"#
```

Answer (score 34):

According to your needs, you may use one of the **4 following patterns** in order to print a Swift `String` that contains double quotes in it.

---

### 1. Using escaped double quotation marks

String literals can include special characters such as `\"`:

```
let string = "A string with \"double quotes\" in it."
print(string) //prints: A string with "double quotes" in it.
```

---

### 2. Using Unicode scalars

String literals can include Unicode scalar value written as `\u{n}`:

```
let string = "A string with \u{22}double quotes\u{22} in it."
print(string) //prints: A string with "double quotes" in it.
```

---

### 3. Using multiline string literals (requires Swift 4)

The [*The Swift Programming Language / Strings and Characters*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) states:

> Because multiline string literals use three double quotation marks instead of just one, you can include a double quotation mark (`"`) inside of a multiline string literal without escaping it.

```
let string = """
A string with "double quotes" in it.
"""
print(string) //prints: A string with "double quotes" in it.
```

---

### 4. Using raw string literals (requires Swift 5)

The [*The Swift Programming Language / Strings and Characters*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) states:

> You can place a string literal within extended delimiters to include special characters in a string without invoking their effect. You place your string within quotation marks (`"`) and surround that with number signs (`#`). For example, printing the string literal `#"Line 1\nLine 2"#` prints the line feed escape sequence (`\n`) rather than printing the string across two lines.

```
let string = #"A string with "double quotes" in it."#
print(string) //prints: A string with "double quotes" in it.
```

Answer (score 26):

For completeness, from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html):

> String literals can include the following special characters:
>
> - The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t
>     (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>     quote) and \' (single quote)
> - An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as
>     \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to
>     a valid Unicode code point

which means that apart from being able to escape the character with backslash, you can use the unicode value. Following two statements are equivalent:

```
let myString = "I love \"unnecessary\" quotation marks"
let myString = "I love \u{22}unnecessary\u{22} quotation marks"
```

`myString` would now contain:

> I love "unnecessary" quotation marks