# Difficulty putting inverted double quotes within double quotes?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, sprite-kit, escaping

I have a simple but annoying problem. I have the following SKLabelNode with the following text for example:

```
Label.text = "click on bob the button"
```

But what I would like to do is this:

```
Label.text = "click on "bob" the button"
```

But it won't let me put double quotes within double quotes. Any way around this?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167848/how-to-print-double-quotes-inside/30167900#30167900 It's called "escaping" the double quote (not double comma). :)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking online but couldn't find the right wording to describe my problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to scape it by adding `\` before it,like this:

```
Label.text = "click on \"bob\" the button"
```