# Swift beginners about adding charcters to a string

Tags: string, swift

In Lazarus/Delphi you can add different characters to a string like:

```
// Gives a string Back like '....'
function SingleQuotedStr (St: String) : String;
begin
  SingleQuotedStr := Chr(39)+ St + Chr(39);
end;    // SingleQuotedStr
```

In swift it's then

```
func SingleQuotedStr (St: String) -> String
{
    return "'"+St + "'"
}    // SingleQuotedStr
```

But How do i make it DoubleQuoted?

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30167900/2227743

Comment: I've linked to a duplicate where I've got an answer (there's many others of course). If this wasn't what you actually needed, please [edit] your question with more information and details, and users will be able to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score -3):

Use backslash before the double quote to ignore it from ending the string

var str = "Hello my name is \"Ryan\". "