# Dictionary keys and values losing quotation marks ("") when variable passed in as AnyObject in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am creating a dictionary in Swift of type [String: AnyObject] which contains key:value pairs along with nested dictionaries. Each item is cast as an AnyObject. However only the key:value pairs of the outer dictionary carry the quotation marks ("") around the strings. The key:value pairs of the nested dictionaries lose them all together. I cast the entire nested dictionary as an AnyObject element.

```
let parameter: [String: AnyObject] = [
                   "cartonNumber": "\(cartonNumber)" as AnyObject,
                   "status": "DELIVERED" as AnyObject,
                   "documentNumbers":
                       [
                         "\"shipmentNumber\"": "\(currentShipmentNumber)",
                        "referenceNumber": "\(referenceNumber)",
                        "proNumber": "\(proNumber)",
                        "billOfLadingNumber": "\(bolNumber)",
                        "trackingNumber": "\(trackingNumber)"
                       ] as AnyObject,
                           "sourceLocation": [
                                "plantCode":"1028"
                           ] as AnyObject,
            "targetLocation": [
                           "id":"73e64de9-36cd-4b20-be1d-13003e455008",
                           "type":"store/stores"
                       ] as AnyObject,
            "shipDate": "\(dateToday)" as AnyObject,
            "items": [
            "\"product\"": [
                "gtin":"00004007334274"
                ],
            "quantity": 2,
            "documentNumbers":
                [
          "deliveryNumber": "\(deliveryNumber)"
            ],
               ] as AnyObject
        ]
```

Looking to keep the quotation marks around the key:values in the nested dictionaries

Comment: you don't need add `AnyObject` in each value, with this line `let parameter: [String: AnyObject]` you already said that the value will be `AnyObject`.

what will you do with dictionary?

Comment: JSON collection types are never reference type, they are value type (`Any`). This avoids all these pointless bridge casts.

Comment: @AndresGomez I am passing it into a function that requires a [String: AnyObject] type. The cartonNumber, is coming through in quotes but all other strings the "" are taken away

Answer (score 0):

If I print your JSON in debugger I got this output. it seems all the "" are correct. Can you please explain what exactly you are trying?

```
(lldb) po parameter
▿ 7 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "items"
    ▿ value : 3 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : documentNumbers
        ▿ value : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : deliveryNumber
            - value : 7
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "product"
        ▿ value : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : gtin
            - value : 00004007334274
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : quantity
        - value : 2
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "documentNumbers"
    ▿ value : 5 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : proNumber
        - value : 3
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        ▿ key : "shipmentNumber"
        - value : 1
      ▿ 2 : 2 elements
        - key : referenceNumber
        - value : 2
      ▿ 3 : 2 elements
        - key : trackingNumber
        - value : 5
      ▿ 4 : 2 elements
        ▿ key : billOfLadingNumber
        - value : 4
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - key : "shipDate"
    - value : 6
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    - key : "sourceLocation"
    ▿ value : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : plantCode
        - value : 1028
  ▿ 4 : 2 elements
    - key : "targetLocation"
    ▿ value : 2 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : type
        - value : store/stores
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : id
        ▿ value : 73e64de9-36cd-4b20-be1d-13003e455008
  ▿ 5 : 2 elements
    - key : "status"
    - value : DELIVERED
  ▿ 6 : 2 elements
    - key : "cartonNumber"
    - value : 0
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want save the quotes use this example

```
let sentence = "They said \"It's okay\", didn't they?"

print(sentence)
```

> They said "It's okay", didn't they?

Comment: Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167900/2227743