# Double quotes in HTML in Swift Playgrounds WKWebView?

Tags: swiftui, wkwebview, swift-playground

How do I use HTML that has double quotes("") in a Swift Playgrounds(iPad)  WKWebView?

I tried to do it this way using \ before the quotes:
Note, this was done in a playground not a app.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let myURL = URL(string:"https://www.apple.com")

class WebViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        self.view = webView
    }
    
    var webView: WKWebView { self.view as! WKWebView }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe frameborder=\”0\” src=\”https://itch.io/embed/2292016\” width=\”552\” height=\”167\”><a href=\”https://v205.itch.io/ghost-battle\”>Ghost Battle by V205</a></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
    }
}

let vc = WebViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

But it gives a error:
`Invalid escape sequence in literal`

Here is the HTML that I tried to use:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://itch.io/embed/2292016" width="552" height="167"><a href="https://v205.itch.io/ghost-battle">Ghost Battle by V205</a></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one of these solutions helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906872/16157878

Comment: @sounflix Thanks, I tried solution one but the error still happens. I will try the rest later....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the methods outlined here: [How to print double quotes inside ""?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906872/16157878)

For example, to use [Extended String Delimiters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Extended-String-Delimiters), enclose your quoted string with the *Number Sign* `#`.

Apart from *Quotation Mark* `"`, your string also contains the *Right Double Quotation Mark* `”`, which needs to be replaced with `"`.

Finally the line in your example becomes this:

```
self.webView.loadHTMLString(#"<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://itch.io/embed/2292016" width="552" height="167"><a href="https://v205.itch.io/ghost-battle">Ghost Battle by V205</a></iframe>"#, baseURL: nil)
```